# Aspectj expression to capture classes with specific name patterns

Tags: aspectj

I need advice on writing the aspectj expression to find all classes with the class name pattern.

Below is the expression I have now to capture the method servletImplementation() from the main package flow.  I would like to tweak it more to do weaving only on the classes that has name ends with *Log.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
@After("execution(* flow..servletImplementation(..))")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the asterisk wildcard should work just fine for you:

Classes starting 'flow':

```
@After("execution(* flow*.servletImplementation(..))")
```

Classes with names starting Foo somewhere below a root package of flow:

```
@After("execution(* flow..Foo*.servletImplementation(..))")
```